# Get host name from IP address

Tags: c#

I have managed to get the connected clients IP with the code below but can't seem to get the hostname.

```
Globals.connectedIPAddress = "" + IPAddress.Parse(((
    IPEndPoint)_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString());
```

Comment: Just curious: Does your ToString-Parse-ToString mess have any purpose?

Comment: Newbie bud. If there is a cleaner way then I would like to know please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, not every IP address *has* a name. However, given the `IPAddress` you can use [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143996.aspx) to *try* to resolve it. Also note that if it's being a NAT router, you'll be getting the router's IP address rather than their actual machine.

And just to address the point in the comments, I agree that there's no point in ToString/Parse/ToString:

```
IPAddress address = ((IPEndPoint)_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
Globals.connectedIPAddress = address.ToString();
```

Comment: @ if it's being a NAT router, you'll be getting the router's IP address rather than their actual machine. - Is it possible to get the actual machine name(domain name) ?

Comment: @JonSkeet is there no better way than this (2.5 years later)? On my network this method throws an exception Every Time.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: Networking hasn't changed that much since 2010 as far as I'm aware...

Comment: yeah, I agree, just thought that .NET might have added some tools to get more reliable. I "could" use this method, except it doesn't fail gracefully. If it doesn't get the HostName, it throws an exception.