# How to know get the IP address from the FTP address

Tags: c#, .net

This is my ftp:

```
ftp://192.168.2.4
```

I want to take the `192.168.2.4`

#### What I tried

```
string ipAddress = FTPAddress.Substring(5,11)
```

that works

#### The problem

as you see, I set the length to `11`, however, when I change the ftp address, that `11` won't work and I would need the new ftp address length. could you help please

**maybe reguralr expression?**

#### Update

Sometimes the ftp address could be like this:
    `ftp://ip/folder`

Comment: Possible Regex for IP: `\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b` (does not check if all bytes are <= 255)

Answer (score 6):

Create an `Uri` object. IP address will be in `Host` property.

```
Uri link = new Uri("ftp://192.168.2.4");
string IpAddress = link.Host;
```

`Uri` class can also provide more [useful information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Uri_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the URI Class for handling the address then use the Host Property to read that portion of it.

```
Uri ftpAddress = new Uri("ftp://192.168.2.4");
string ipAddress = ftpAddress.Host;
```

And if you need to convert Hostnames to IPAddresses the following extension class might help (based on this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13249025/2594742)):

```
public static class UriHostResolveExtension
{
    public static String ResolveHostnameToIp(this Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Dns)
        {
            IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(uri.Host);
            if (hostEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
                return hostEntry.AddressList[0].ToString();
        }
        return uri.Host;
    }
}
```

Can be used in the following scenario:

```
Uri ftpAddress = new Uri("ftp://example.com/");
string ipAddress = ftpAddress.ResolveHostnameToIp();
```